# Is there any requirement that airports have distinct names?

Tags: airport

Is there any requirement that airports have reasonably distinct names from each other?

I've known about SYD versus YQY for a while, but I've just read that there's two airports mentioning Genghis Khan: ULN in Mongolia and NZL in Inner Mongolia in the PRC.

Comment: No. As well as your examples there are two airports called Billy Bishop in Ontario.

Comment: That's why names are not used for flight planning =)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid the pilot in this article must have used names: [Airport mix-up sees Winter Olympics delegation land in Pyongyang after pilot files wrong flight plan](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/04/02/airport-mix-up-sees-winter-olympics-delegation-land-pyongyang/)

Answer (score 2):

There's no requirement for names. Location codes can't be the same though.

Comment: Rather than a location code, I believe the correct term would be the airport identifier.